# bigstore increasing almost linearly Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I use many api's from Google Cloud. Recently I noticed that the bigstore is gradually increasing on a daily basis. I am worried that if this continues I wont be able to pay the bill.

[image]

I do not know however how to check where this increase is coming from. Is there a way to see which cloud functions are causing this increased traffic?

The reason I am surprised about the increase in the traffic of bigstore is because I have cron jobs that are running multiple times per day to store the data in BigQuery. I have not changed these settings, so I would assume that this traffic should not increase as shown on the chart.

One other explanation I can think of is that the amount of data that I am storing has increased, which is indeed true on a daily basis. But why does this increase the traffic?

What is the way to check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main data sources you should use:

1. GCP-wide [billing export](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file). This will tell you an exact breakdown of your costs. This is important to make sure you target your effort where the cost is largest to you. It also provides some level of detail about what the usage is.
2. Enable [access & storage logging](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs). The access log will give you an exact accounting of incoming requests down to the number of bytes transferred. The storage logs give you similar granularity into the cost of storage itself.

Comment: In addition, Google Cloud provides Stackdriver, which you can use to analyze the logs mentioned here and organize the data in the logs and determine where the data is coming from (and to set up alarms).

Comment: Does that also work when you are in a trial period? That is exactly the problem I think as the costs are now zero, but I seem my trial credit significantly decreasing.

Comment: Both of these work in free trial. The billing export includes both the usage and credits applied against that usage. Access/storage logs just show usage regardless of how it's paid for. Note that you are charged for the cost of storing/downloading the usage reports themselves too, at regular GCS pricing.

Comment: So I did what you mentioned, but when I use for instance the billing export the sum adds up to only 4USD, whereas in my billing view I loose approx 20-30USD per day. I cannot identify where it comes from from this file?

Comment: The billing export should match what you are actually being charged. If there is a discrepency, I suggest [reaching out to the free billing support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) as they can look at the raw data to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you have a snapshot of your bigstore, as time goes on and you replace or even rename files, your storage charges will increase because where once you had 2 views of the same storage, as the files change each file forks in 2 copies (one is the current view of your storage, one is the snapshot.)